# Querying Azure App Service Backend From Localhost

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I recently migrated my app backend from azure mobile services to azure app services.  I am using the node.js backend with multiple "easy tables" and "easy api's".

After configuring CORS all of my sites that query this backend are up and running properly.

Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out how to query this backend from localhost.  I have tried running sites hosted on my local machine that use the exact same code as working sites hosted elsewhere.  I have also tried using postman.  All of these attempts result in a 400 bad request error.

Edited o be more clear.  I have a migrated azure mobile service running on azure.  I am attempting to hit that endpoint from localhost.  I have tried to hit this endpoint using postman.  I have also tried to hit this endpoint using a locally hosted copy of a website that is currently working when not hosted locally.  All requests from localhost end up with a 400 error.

I have added https://localhost, localhost:portnumber, https://myIp to the cors page.  On the application settings page my MS_CrossDomainWhitelist setting contains [{"host":"localhost"}] (I have also tried without this setting).  I have also tried setting MS_SkipVersionCheck to true.  What am I missing?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do.  If I may:  You have an Azure Mobile Service (migrated) running in Azure.  You have downloaded the code and are attempting to run the Node.js code locally, then hitting the endpoint locally (e.g. http://localhost:3000/tables/foo) using Postman.  It's getting a 400 Bad Request.  Is that correct?

Comment: I have a migrated azure mobile service running on azure.  I am attempting to hit the endpoint https://myserver.azure-mobile.net/tables/foo.  I have tried to hit this endpoint using postman.  I have also tried to hit it using a locally hosted copy of a website that is working properly when hosted elsewhere.  Both methods give me a 400 error

Comment: Can you post a sample request (+headers) that results in 400 Bad Request?

Comment: Since you have tried to set `MS_SkipVersionCheck` to true for opting out version checking of the key [ZUMO-API-VERSION](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/#2.0.0) in the HTTP header or the query string. Could you please provide the detailed response message when you getting a 400 Bad Request?

Comment: It's not a CORS issue.  So, you can cross that off your list.  Go into your website, turn on Diagnostic Logging, then look at the Log Stream - do the request via Postman and see what you can see.  Add the Request, Response and Logs to your question.